# When i attach i don't see console in readable text

Tags: tmux

I have a perl script running that leaves print outputs to the console.When i detach using (Ctrl+B D) it detaches. If i attach again, i don't see the console output in plain text. I see as such :

```
 â¼ecâºâ¼d 717433 ââ¼â½eâ¼âed
 ââ¼â½eâ¼âââ¼Â± ââ½ â»âââ :  1 â172193 â717433
 ââ¼â½eâ¼âââ¼Â± ââ½ â»âââ :  2 â196â®1 â717433
 ââ¼â½eâ¼âââ¼Â± ââ½ â»âââ :  3 â14835 â717433
 ââ¼â½eâ¼âââ¼Â± ââ½ â»âââ :  4 â3352 â717433
```

Why is it like this ? and how may i get back a readable view ?

Comment: Did you try the command `reset`?

Comment: How may i send a reset ? will this affect the session ?

Comment: I mean you have to type into the shell the command. Maybe you need to pause the perl script.